# For MacOS pthreads, sigwait() Does Not Handle a Signal

Tags: macos, pthreads, signals

When running the following, the sigwait() never handles the `SIGUSR1` signal.  Basic setup is: main spawns two pthreads: one a handler thread and one a worker thread.  The main thread and both spawned threads block SIGUSR1.  The worker raises SIGUSR1 twice with a two second delay.  The handler thread never sees it.

This is on MacOS.  When running from Xcode I insert a continuable breakpoint that executes `pro hand -p true -s false SIGUSR1`.  If I run the executable from the command line, the same output occurs.

Why does `sigwait()` not see the raised SIGUSR1?

Here is the output:

```
SigHandlerThread: Waiting: 30
Raise
Raise
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Here is the code:

```
//
// Signal Test
//
typedef void* (*ThreadRoutine) (void*);         // pthread_create

void workerRaise (int signum) {
  sleep (2);
  printf ("Raise\n");
  raise (signum);
}

void sigBlock (sigset_t *set, int signum) {
  sigemptyset(set);
  sigaddset(set, signum);
  pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, set, NULL);
}

void *sigHandlerThread (void *ignore) {
  int signal;

  sigset_t blockSignalSet;
  sigBlock(&blockSignalSet, SIGUSR1);

  printf ("SigHandlerThread: Waiting: %d\n", SIGUSR1);

  while (0 == sigwait(&blockSignalSet, &signal))
    printf ("SigHandlerThread: %d\n", signal);

  printf ("SigHandlerThread: Exit (0 != sigwait())\n");
  return NULL;
}

void *workerThread (void *ignore) {
  sigset_t blockSignalSet;
  sigBlock(&blockSignalSet, SIGUSR1);

  workerRaise(SIGUSR1);
  workerRaise(SIGUSR1);

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Called from main.
void testSignal () {
  sigset_t blockSignalSet;
  sigBlock(&blockSignalSet, SIGUSR1);

  pthread_t worker, handler;
  pthread_create (&handler, NULL, (ThreadRoutine) sigHandlerThread, NULL);
  pthread_create (&worker,  NULL, (ThreadRoutine) workerThread, NULL);
  pthread_join(worker, NULL);
  sleep (2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `raise()` function sends the signal directed specifically at the calling thread - other threads in the process won't receive it.  `raise(signum)` is equivalent to `pthread_kill(pthread_self(), signum)`.

What you need is a process-directed signal, not a thread-directed signal.  Instead of using `raise(signum)`, use `kill(getpid(), signum)`.

Comment: My goal is a have a single thread handle the signal; therefore, `pthread_kill (handler, SIGUSR1)` achieves that and a 'process-directed signal' is not needed.  Given that I can direct the signal, I do not need to block SIGUSR1 in the 'main' and 'worker' threads?

Comment: @GoZoner: That's right (but it does have the slight downside that your signalling thread needs to keep a handle to the handler thread).